# How to display name of variables in plots in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Hi guys I have a list of 2-D coordinates that I assigned one to one to a list of variables (i.e. x[i]), but i want show the variable names on list plots but don't know how to.

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When  you want Mathematica's default behavior, for example: a variable name is immediately replaced with the value assigned to that variable, things are often fairly simple. But when you want to change that default behavior things are usually much more complicated.

Try this

```
values = {{1, 5}, {2, 7}, {3, 4}};
SetAttributes[fun, {HoldFirst, Listable}];
fun[v_] := ToString[Unevaluated[v]];
g1 = Show[ListPlot[values], 
  Graphics[Text[#[[1]], #[[2]], {0, 1}] & /@ 
    Transpose[{Flatten[fun[{x[1], x[2], x[3]}]], values}]]]
```

[image]

Usually I recommend new users study each part of an answer, read the help pages, take it apart, see how each piece works, make little changes until you understand how you can adapt that in the future. But in this case I think just hope that it works for you as is.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`Labeled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html) data wrapper syntax of [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html).

With

```
values = {{1, 5}, {2, 7}, {3, 4}};
```

then

```
ListPlot[
 MapIndexed[Labeled[#1, StringJoin["x[", ToString@First@#2, "]"]] &]@values
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.